# dynamically assign attribute id to <p:tab> in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay, primefaces-extensions

I have created tabs dynamically and I am trying to assign it attribute id which is not working.....or any other way to get the title of the clicked tab?

```
<p:accordionPanel value="#{displayassestDto.getgroups()}" var="d">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{displayassestDto.onTabChange}" update=":form:growl"/>
       <p:tab title="#{d.group}" id="tab_#{d.group}">
           <h:outputLabel value="Helllooo" />
            </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> any other way to get the title of the clicked tab?

Yes, `onTabChange` can be modified to accept an object of type `TabChangeEvent`. On this object, you can retrieve the tab that fired the event. Your code will look something like

```
       public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent evt){
            evt.getTab(); // on this tab object returned, you can get the id, title etc
        }
```

As to why the code you have is not working right now, it's probably because the state of the  output of `getGroups()` is not consistent throughout the request processing. Ensure you're not carrying out any business logic or processing in `getGroups()`. But you really don't need to do any of that.

Comment: yes you are right, but there is another problem in onTabChange method 
`evt.getTab().getTitle;` returns an empty string

Comment: @user2100148 Try setting a static id and title, to confirm that the `getGroups` method is buggy